# choosing a hosting platform that allows file and directory creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to launch a project where my **server generates user files and directories**. Since heroku doesn't allow that, i am trying to find the best platform that will fit my needs without changing a bunch of my code.

my node server is storing data to firebase along with some files on the server itself. I realize this is not best practice but it is what it is for now

What would you recommend?

Comment: Use S3 with your Heroku app instead of moving your entire app to a different hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your objects in S3. Do not store files on VMs in case of any failure.

Comment: why @taskiner??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, an EBS volume would be a good start.  It is meant to be redundant and the chances of losing any data is very small.  The advantage is that it lives on if you terminate or stop an instance.

The newer EFS is very fast and can be mounted to multiple machines, much like an NFS file system.  It is redundant across availability zones and will also survive a machine stop/termination.

S3 is an object store and isn't really meant for file system I/O. It can easily store files but it doesn't have nearly the performance of either EBS or EFS.  It lives on after machine termination - indeed, it can be accessed with HTTP when properly configured.

Ultimately, you can create files normally on the EC2 with instance store, EBS, or EFS.  The instance store data is lost if you terminate or even stop the instance.  Be careful with that - you can easily lose tons of data when it is on instance store and not properly backed up.